# Selection SQL where two conditions must be true

Tags: mysql, sql

What's the most efficient way to select rows that must satisfy two conditions met in the same column?

```
name | title
------------------
John | Associate
John | Manager
Fran | Manager
Fran | President
```

I'd like to do something like

```
select name 
  from table 
 where title = 'Associate' 
   and name in ( select * 
                   from table 
                  where title = 'Manager')
```

which should return

```
John
```

but that seems woefully inefficient, especially if the table itself is super big. You could also do

```
select name 
  from table a, 
       table b 
 where a.title = 'Associate' 
   and b.title = 'Manager' 
   and a.name = b.name
```

Is that the best one can do?

Comment: `and name in ( select * ...` don't use * in that situation

Answer (score 1):

Your first query is not syntactically correct.  It should be:

```
select name
from table
where title = 'Associate' and
     name in (select name from table where title = 'Manager');
```

The second is better written as a `join`:

```
select name
from table a join
     table b
     on a.title = 'Associate' and b.title = 'Manager' and a.name = b.name;
```

The second is probably better in terms of taking advantage of indexes on the table.

You can also do this with a `group by`:

```
select name
from table a
group by name
having sum(title = 'Associate') > 0 and sum(title = 'Manager') > 0;
```

MySQL is not very good at optimizing `group by`.  But if there are no indexes on the table, it might be faster than the `join` methods.

Comment: If there was another row that had John, Manager, what would be the best way to ensure that John is returned just once? Use a distinct?

Comment: @Rio . . . The third method using `group by` would do this.  Once you put `distinct` in, you are probably doing an aggregation anyways (under the hood), so you might as well do this directly.

Answer (score 1):

I would have an index on your table via ( title, name ), then do a self-join. In this case, I am putting what would be less probable as the outer primary condition of the query where the manager records are considered first... ie. a company may have 5 managers and 100 associates vs looking for 100 associates that match the 5 managers.

```
select
      t.name 
   from 
      table t
         join table t2
            on t2.title = 'Associate' 
           AND t.name = t2.name
   where 
      t.title = 'Manager'
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not a whole lot of data given as an example, but I'm assuming both John's here are the same person with multiple titles?  If that were the case you would be better off having your titles being a child table of the employees table (if that's what this table is)

So instead you could have:

```
Employee
----
id
name

titles
----
id
titleName

employeeTitles
----
employeeId
titleId
```

If you can't do it this way, i would think another way to write your original query would be:

```
select name 
from table t1
inner join (
    select distinct name
    from table
    where title = 'manager'
) t2 on t1.name = t2.name
where title = 'Associate'
```

could also do group by name rather than distinct.  But still, doing the above solution i think would be better all around (assuming my own assumptions are correct about your data)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on MySQL Version (MySQL 5.6 has query rewrite feature which improves `IN()` subquery) and Table Relationships.

There are at least 3 ways to get result you're expecting. In my experience, `INNE JOIN` is faster than others in general cases.

Try your self with your data.

## IN () - you've wrote firstly.

please note that in MySQL. `IN()` produces `dependent sub-query` plan.

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM table
WHERE title = 'Associate'
  AND name IN (SELECT name FROM table WHERE title = 'Manager')
```

## SELF JOIN - your 2nd

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM table t1 INNER JOIN table t2
WHERE a.title = 'Associate' AND b.title = 'Manager'
  AND t1.name = t2.name
```

## EXISTS - Semi JOIN

`EXISTS` is fast when tables have 1:n relationship. This requires no `DISTINCT`, `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT name
FROM table t1
WHERE a.title = 'Associate'
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table t2
              WHERE t2.name = t1.name AND t2.title = 'Manager')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using WHERE EXISTS (or NOT EXISTS) is a very effective alternative for this

```
select
        name
from table1
where title = 'Associate' 
and exists (
            select 1 /* could be: select NULL as nothing actually needs to be "returned */
            from table1 as t2
            where t2.title = 'Manager'
            and t2.name = table1.name /* correlated here */
           )
;
```

Similar to using IN() it requires a subquery but "correlates" that subquery. However this subquery does NOT need to move any data (IN can require this).

Also, similar to IN() using EXISTS has no impact on the number of result rows. Joins can create unwanted row repetition (but of course sometimes the extra rows are needed).

[This reference](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join) is for SQL Server, but it compares several relevant methods (ignore Outer Apply - mssql specific), including potential issues dealing with NULLs when using IN() that do not affect EXISTS

| NOT | EXISTS () should be one of the first methods to consider.

Comment: IMO, poor choice to use correlated sub-queries.  Yes, they work, but poor on performance, especially in larger data sets.

Comment: @DRapp: Sorry, that is utterly untrue of EXISTS. Take another look at the facts. I agree with you 100% if using a correlated subquery inside the select clause - but this is completely not true here. Do read the article mentioned. Finally: IN() is much, much!, worse in large data sets than exists.

Comment: appreciate the comment, and did review in more detail the link you provided.  Thanks